# Hidden feature on the Search box in SO

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, search

I wanted to search for questions which have `"Dynamic IN clause in SQL server"` on Stack Overflow. Instead I added the search string as `"Dynamic IN"` and pressed `[ENTER]`. Unusually, my search string changed itself to `[dynamic]` in the search text box and it started treating the dynamic as a tag name and search results showed me questions related to [dynamic](/questions/tagged/dynamic).

Similarly I tried with other words like Java, C# etc as `"Java IN"`, `"C# IN"` and as expected, all these words also turned out to be tags. However I then added search string as `"abc IN"`, but in this case the text in search box remained as just `"abc IN"` only.

So is this some hidden feature of Search box to search for tags and if those tags exist in SO, then it will start searching for questions with those tags else retains its string in search? Also if I really want to search for `"Dynamic IN"`, how do I do that?

Comment: The search function has auto-tagified keywords for a long time. It's got nothing to do with "IN".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a keyword is a tag then it's converted into a tag search.

"Java", "Dynamic" and "C#" are all tags, but "abc" isn't.

To search for a word that's a tag as just the word prefix it by "+". So your search will be:

> +dynamic in clause ...

Also words like "in" and "or" etc are ignored in the search (or at least they used to be).